# Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. Prove $(X,d')$ is a complete metric space such that $d'=\max\{1,d\}$

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space.

Prove $(X,d')$ is a complete metric space such that $d'=\max\{1,d\}$

Can't figure out why this statement is correct.

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a cauchy-sequence.

By definition of  cauchy-sequence $\exists N\geq1$ such that $d(x_n,x_m)<1,\forall n,m>N.$

It follows that $d'(x_n,x_m)=1 \forall n,m>N$ , this is not cauchy-sequence.

Where am I wrong ?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: It is bad manners to change your question after someone has already answered it. If your question wasn't what you meant to ask, you should put more thought into your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$d'=\max\{1, d\}\ge 1$ is not a metric.

Comment: $d'\geq 1 \implies d'=d$ , d is indeed a metric. Why d' isn't a metric ? this statement isn't false ?

Comment: $d'=\max\{1,d\}\\\implies d'(x,y)=\max\{1,d(x,y)\}$$$d'\ge 1\\\implies d'(x, y) \ge 1\text{for all }x, y\in X$$

Comment: For $x=y$ we have $d'(x, y) \ge 1$

Comment: Thanks,now I get it ,suppose $x\neq y$ then $d'$ is a metric and this statement is correct ?

Comment: $d'(x, x) =\max\{1, d(x, x) \}=1$

Comment: $d'(x,x)=0 , d'(x,y)=\max\{1,d(x,y)\},x\neq y$

Comment: I think you are talking about $$d'(x,y)=\begin{cases} \max\{1, d(x, y) \}&x\neq y\\0&x=y\end{cases}$$

Comment: Exactly what I am talking about. I fixed my question. appreciate any help with my question.

Comment: The original question has been answered.Changing question after getting an answer is not a good practice and shouldn't be encouraged.